# JavaScript: Generate current date with custom format

Tags: javascript, date-format, shortcut, shortcode

I am trying to generate the current date in the `Date Month, Year` format. Currently I am using following code:

```js
function currentDate() 
{
    var months = [
        'Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 
        'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'
    ];

    var date = new Date();
    var d = date.getDate();
    var m = date.getMonth();
    var y = date.getFullYear();

    return `${d} ${months[m]}, ${y}`;
}
```

Although, It's works perfectly. But, is there a shorter way to do this..?

Something like:

```js
(new Date()).format('d M, Y')
```

Comment: You should check [moment](https://www.npmjs.com/package/moment) library which implement interfaces like you want.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to format a JavaScript date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552461/how-to-format-a-javascript-date)

Comment: @Xeelley Moment library got deprecated.

Comment: @Xeelley [luxon](https://moment.github.io/luxon) is moment's successor

Comment: Actually, I am trying to refactor and reduce the code. Therefore, I am not in favor of including any external library. I thought this can be reduced as well, so I posted the question.

Comment: @BenFortune, I have already seen that question and it did not help as I have mentioned in my last comment.

Comment: As suggested in my answer and in the linked question, you can use [`Intl.DateTimeFormat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat) instead

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, there isnt.

But you can use libraries like [luxon](https://moment.github.io/luxon):

```js
DateTime.now().toFormat('d M, Y')
```

Or, if you want to stay native, you can use [`Intl.DateTimeFormat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat):

```js
new Intl.DateTimeFormat('es-US', { dateStyle: 'full' }).format(d);
```

However, ECMAScript currently has a proposal to improve `Date` class by adding [`Temporal`](https://tc39.es/proposal-temporal/docs/index.html) global object:

```js
Temporal.now.date().toLocaleString('es-US', {
  weekday: 'long',
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no simple way to do that. Instead, you could see other alternatives.

If you are already using `new Date()` all over the application. I suggest [dayjs](https://day.js.org/docs/en/parse/now). It has all the date-utilities you are looking for.

It works with `new Date()` object also.